# does old off-page techniques work?

Tags: seo, ranking

There was a time when blog commenting, social bookmarking, forum posting used to work on niche related sites but now does it work any longer?

Comment: Using your list of options, I would have to say No.

Comment: Google largely ignores links within the elements listed by the OP therefore there is no value whatsoever. As well, Google views these as prime locations for spam links and may likely view any link profile consisting of such links as spam heavy. So No. These are lousy places to look for links. Google wants to see organic earned links. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it does work! It has changed a little but still helps SEO or at least to drive traffic.

Just keep in mind:

- if you create an article on someone's else website and have backlinks pointing to your site you might get a good link. However there is no guarantee. Just check if articles written by someone else in the same section are being indexed and what attribute links have.
- if you just comment with your link most likely you might get couple hits to your site, but it won't be a good link. I call it ghost links. Most comments has `no follow` attributes and you might not even see it in your backlink portfolio.

I'd recommend you to focus on social media and social bookmarks. It helps SEO more than simple guest blogging/commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes these methods are still beneficial for the SEO. Creating back link is good option for getting index to our websites. The back links from good forums make good result on SERP result.

These are good methods, but not the only. There is plenty to be found on this matter on Google, like link structures, fast loading and good content.

Comment: When you downvote, motivate why so the user can improve their answer, *especially* for new users. There isn't anything downvote-worthy in this answer.

Comment: @Martijn, Might because its bad advice? creating forum links is bad SEO.

Comment: Do you have any sources? I'd like to read that. IMO creating some good content on forums with a link to your own site here and there will have a possitive effect. Same requirement as normal content, it has to be good.

Comment: @Martijin This list has a few from the OPs list toward the bottom. https://moz.com/blog/17-types-of-link-spam-to-avoid Cheers!!

Comment: I doubt why OP mark this as accepted answer(What if other people visit this page and think "yeah this might still work", so they waste their more time on it other than creating great content with good promotion strategy). I can write 5000 words on that, why such type of links never work.

Comment: OP is a new user, and just clicked 'accept', OP is probally not used to waiting for another answer to show up :)